# RxSwift API response

Tags: swift, rx-swift

I am bamboozled by the following code that works if I uncomment the commented code below. If I comment it, it doesn't work. I have no idea about what the issue is :

```swift
func getMostPopularRepositories(byLanguage language: String) -> Observable<[Repository]> {
  let encodedLanguage = language.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: CharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed)!

  let provider = MoyaProvider<Github>(plugins: [NetworkLoggerPlugin(verbose: true)])
  let parameters = [“q”: “language:\(encodedLanguage)“,“sort”: “stars”]

  /*
  provider.rx
    .request(.repositories(parameters))
    .map([Repository].self, atKeyPath: “items”)
    .subscribe { event in
  }.dispose()
  */

  let request = provider.rx.request(.repositories(parameters)).asObservable()
  // RxSwift.(unknown context at $101ccc3e8).AnonymousObservable<Moya.Response>
  print(request)
  let pRepos = request.map([Repository].self, atKeyPath: “items”)
  // RxSwift.(unknown context at $101ccf26c).FlatMap<Moya.Response, RxSwift.Observable<Swift.Array<RepoSearcher.Repository>>>
  print(pRepos)
  return pRepos
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven‘t worked with `Moya` yet.

But it seems that you need to `.subscribe` to make `.request` work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to subscribe to pRepos observable to send the network request as the observable waits until an observer subscribes to it before it begins to emit items, and starts pushing values to the observers when subscribe is called.

So in your case

```
func getMostPopularRepositories(byLanguage language: String) -> Observable<[Repository]> {
    let encodedLanguage = language.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: CharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed)!

    let provider = MoyaProvider<Github>(plugins: [NetworkLoggerPlugin(verbose: true)])
    let parameters = [“q”: “language:\(encodedLanguage)“,“sort”: “stars”]

    let request = provider.rx.request(.repositories(parameters)).asObservable()
    // RxSwift.(unknown context at $101ccc3e8).AnonymousObservable<Moya.Response>
    print(request)
    let pRepos = request.map([Repository].self, atKeyPath: “items”)
    // RxSwift.(unknown context at $101ccf26c).FlatMap<Moya.Response, RxSwift.Observable<Swift.Array<RepoSearcher.Repository>>>
    print(pRepos)
    return pRepos
}
```

// code which subscribe to the Observable<[Repository]>

```
let disposeBag = DisposeBag()
let popularReposObservable: Observable<[Repository]> =   getMostPopularRepositories(byLanguage: "English")
popularReposObservable
    .observeOn(MainScheduler.instance)
    .subscribe(onNext: { (popularRepos: [Repository]) in
        print(popularRepos)
    })
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```